# NSLog-like logging framework for iOS

Tags: swift, logging

I am writing a [logging framework for iOS](https://github.com/QuantumApplications/QLog/tree/c532d68227409da3f7612f46eb769033692e20ed). The idea is to create a behavior similar to `NSLog` to print the log message and some metadata to the console.

The following struct shall hold the data of a log entry:

```
public enum LogLevel: Int {

    case highlight = 4
    case debug = 3
    case info = 2
    case warning = 1
    case error = 0

}

public struct LogEntry {

    let date: Date
    let file: String
    let function: String
    let line: Int
    let logLevel: LogLevel
    let text: String

    var metaText: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        return "\(dateFormatter.string(from: self.date)): \((self.file as NSString).lastPathComponent):\(self.line) \(self.function): "
    }

}
```

The struct can then be printed with the following function (simplified):

```
public class QLog {

    static func log(_ logEntry: LogEntry) {
        print("\(logEntry.metaText)\(logEntry.text)")
    }

}
```

Of course I want to log from any point in my code like `QLogDebug("Test")`. So, I added the following global functions (I got the idea from https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs):

```
public func QLogHighlight<T>(date: Date = Date(), file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(date: date, file: file, function: function, line: line, logLevel: LogLevel.highlight, text: "\(object)"))
}

public func QLogDebug<T>(date: Date = Date(), file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(date: date, file: file, function: function, line: line, logLevel: LogLevel.debug, text: "\(object)"))
}

public func QLogInfo<T>(date: Date = Date(), file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(date: date, file: file, function: function, line: line, logLevel: LogLevel.info, text: "\(object)"))
}

public func QLogWarning<T>(date: Date = Date(), file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(date: date, file: file, function: function, line: line, logLevel: LogLevel.warning, text: "\(object)"))
}

public func QLogError<T>(date: Date = Date(), file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(date: date, file: file, function: function, line: line, logLevel: LogLevel.error, text: "\(object)"))
}
```

Now, this is a bit ugly because the function signatures are very long as well as the initialization of the LogEntry object. Also, all five functions are the same except the function name and the log level.

So, are there any possibilities to shorten / simplify this code? Can I somehow shorten the signatures? Can I define the functions without copy-pasting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your logging function take a `Date` as the first argument, with a default
value of the current date. Unless there is a special reason why a caller
should pass a custom date, you can remove that argument and compute the
date inside the logging function:

```
public func qLogHighlight<T>(file: String = #file, function: String = #function,
                             line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(date: Date(), file: file, function: function, line: line,
                      logLevel: .highlight, text: "\(object)"))
}
```

or even give the `LogEntry` constructor a default value for the `date`
parameter, so that you can omit it here:

```
public func qLogHighlight<T>(file: String = #file, function: String = #function,
                             line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(file: file, function: function, line: line,
                      logLevel: .highlight, text: "\(object)"))
}
```

Note also that

- function names should start with a lowercase letter (compare [General Conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#general-conventions) in the Swift API Design Guidelines),
- it suffices to pass `.highlight` to the `QLog.log()` call instead
  of `LogLevel.hightlight`, the type is automatically inferred from the
  context.

If you want five separate logging functions, one for each level, then
I do not see more room for shortening. An alternative would be to
define just one logging function which takes the log level as an
argument:

```
public func qLog<T>(level: LogLevel, file: String = #file, function: String = #function,
                    line: Int = #line, _ object: T) {
    QLog.log(LogEntry(date: Date(), file: file, function: function, line: line,
                      logLevel: level, text: "\(object)"))
}
```

This would remove to code duplication completely.

*Some more thoughts:*

Creating a date formatter is “expensive,” it is better to create it once
and reuse it (compare e.g. the “Re-Using Formatter Instances” section in [NSFormatter](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/) on NSHipster.

This can be done with a static property (which is computed lazily and
only once):

```
public struct LogEntry {

    static var formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter
    }()

    ...

}
```

Instead of bridging to `NSString` one can use

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: file).lastPathComponent
```

to get the last path component of a file path.

Apart from special cases (such as escaping closures), properties can
be accessed without using `self`:

```
var metaText: String {
    return "\(LogEntry.formatter.string(from: date)): \(URL(fileURLWithPath: file).lastPathComponent):\(line) \(function): "
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed analysis. I totally forgot  to remove `Date()` from the function signature and to shorten the enums. I did not know that creating formatters is so expensive, I will change that immediately. Is it really better to create an `URL` object from a file path to get the last component? I would have thought that this is more expensive than casting the `String` to `NSString`. Regarding the uppercase function names: I wanted to use the same style as `NSLog`, also starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @sundance: I did not test the efficiency of URL vs NSString, I just wanted to mention an alternative. Generally, the Apple APIs move to using URLs instead of strings for handling file paths, for example, `Process.currentDirectoryPath` has been deprecated in favor of `currentDirectoryURL`. The fastest way (if that is relevant here) would probably be to find the last dot and print the SubString following it.